# Static page determines as home, but it is not

Tags: custom-post-types, pages, homepage, cache

I've registered post type with slug `services`, which means that all content will be under `example.com/services`. Than I decided to remove it, so I deleted this code from `functions.php`.

Now when I create a static page with a name "Services" and url `example.com/services`, but this page and all underpages are determines as **home** pages. But if I create another page with different URL - all fine. They are not home pages. What the problem? Any cache or what?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what do you mean by "determine as home pages" ?

Comment: @Rarst is_home() returns true on static page and <body> tag has "home" class

Comment: This is hard to guess... Something must be messing with main query and it's unlikely to be CPT that is no longer defined.